# Why do linear codes claimed to be spanned by the rows of the generator matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, coding-theory

Why do linear codes claimed to be spanned by the rows of the [generator matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_matrix)?

Don't they spanned by the columns of the generator matrix? i.e.

$$uG = uC_1 + \cdots u C_n = c$$

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_code), "basis codewords are often collated in the rows of a matrix $G$ known as a generating matrix for the code $C$", so that would be by *definition* of generating matrix

Comment: Oh so basically it's a matter of convention, right?

Comment: Notice: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_matrix#cite_note-DrMacKayECC-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you multiply a matrix from the left (by a row vector), you obtain a row vector that is a linear combination of the row vectors of the matrix.